# Can I connect many switches to a switch?

Tags: networking, switch, local-area-network

I am trying to make a campus network.I haven't any experience.
In campus,there are center building and many buildings.I use many switches(for pc,phone,sec-cameras) in a building.And I want to connect these many switches to a switch.So each building will have single switch.And I connect switches to router.there will be a project on paper.So no device or no budget limitations.Coming fiber cables to all buildings.I think to use [this switch](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Cisco-Catalyst-3750X-12S-S-switch-12-ports-managed-rack-mountable/2425669.aspx) for each building and in building,I use any switches(unmanaged).Is this possible?if this is possible,does it occur bottle neck?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be in charge of this project.

Comment: so?I'm student and it's not project, We can say homework.I'm not an expert in this thing, I ask only.

Comment: Do you have any advice other than to unvote?I do not want to build a real structure here.I'm only student not a system expert or engineer.So Do you want to give the idea to a student?You're going to continue to unvote?thanks for reply.

Comment: There are entire certifications dedicated to good design practices for this type of environment.  No simple answer here that will cover all your bases.  But if you want to learn, then look at Cisco's basic design model of Core, Distribution, Access Layer and router L3 links down to access / local Vlans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A network design could look like this. Each building switch double attached (using fiber uplinks) to a failover backbone router at the Center Building.

Default backbone route would be a Firewall.

[image]

Comment: thanks man.I am planning to build this structure.I use RSP with (2-or 3)router(cisco 7500series).And each bulding have a L3 switch and each L3 switch have many L2 switches?can you suggest l3 and l2 switch models/device, please?Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I personally use a Cisco 4500 per floor for buildings, and two Ciso 6500 for backbone using VSL technology as failover

Comment: do you use fiber?the device does not matter but event so Examples device model should be.So I need a device model for L2,L3 switch and router (router and l3 should use fiber).

Comment: Of course i use Fiber ! I am not here to suggest products. Have a look in here and choose the best for your need : http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/index.html

Comment: I know I asked a lot of question for you but what's the name of that drawing program

Comment: Are you kidding ? This is Microsoft Visio

Comment: I had previously used for UML.So thanks man.You know there are many tools for network design.But yours is looking nice and different.So no kidding.Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using routers instead of switches. If the campus is a big one, and there are a lot (lets say 1000+) clients, it does make sense to go for a routed network instead of a big and bloated tree structure. Also, if you do not have enough experience, a Cisco Catalyst will be overkill for you.

Comment: thanks man:) Do you have suggestions fiber-optic router?(for fiber infrastructure) I do not do a real project.I'm trying to establish a working logic with real device.

Comment: I'd go for a Cisco with a HWIC-1GE-SFP card, but that is just a suggestion.

Comment: thanks man.This card is converter(fiber to ge) for router?